# How to mask a specific value without knowing exact key, within a JSON string, in Java

Tags: java, json, string, replace, key-value

I am receiving a JSON in the form of a string, need to mask a piece of information, however the JSON strucutre and key-names are always different but value's pattern is recognizable. Question being, what is an efficient way to traverse through String/JSONObject to mask that piece of data.

I've tried turning the String into a JSONObject and traverse through every embedded JSONObject/Array, detect the pattern, and replace that original value with its masked version. But this seems very time consuming when Logging this information out to console.

Value's pattern for reference is a 9-digit (Long) number.
Structure always varies from "{"key1":[{"innerKey1":123456789}]}" to "{"key1":"value1", "key2":{"innerKey1":123456789}"

Sample result : "{"key1":[{"innerKey1":"XXXXXX789"}]}"

Comment: Could you also post the expected result against the JSON string you received?

Comment: Ultimately I would have to return a String in the following manner, as for the first example I gave herein:  "{"key1":[{"innerKey1":"XXXXXX789"}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JSON structure is always provided as optimized single line string you could just find the value in the string and replace it or get even more elaborate and use a regular expression to find the innerKey1:12345 match and replace that.

If this is just for logging purposes you can even implement this as a filter, depending on your logging framework it might be even configurable instead of having to code it.

Comment: Yes, my first alternative was playing w actual string itself, wondering if there was a JSONObject or ObjectMapper method that I wasn't taking advantage of, but I'll keep on the lookout.